# Проверка регистрации

Tags: php, mysql

Соц. сети, например, Вконтакт сделаны по одному шаблону, а если у меня 3 шаблона, то так можно делать? Всего три таблицы (1, 2, 3). И этот код прописать три раза для 3 таблиц? В еchо лучше прописать три страницы, или путь к страницам?

```
$res_login = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `teacher` WHERE `login` = "' . $_POST['login'] . '"');
if (mysql_num_rows($res_login) != 1)
    echo 'Такой логин не зарегистрирован';
else {
    $row_login = mysql_fetch_array($res_login);
    if ($row_login['password'] != $_POST['password'])
        echo 'Вы ввели не правильно пароль';
    else {
        echo 'Пользователь авторизован';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно делают такую таблицу, вместо 3х:

```
id | login | password | type ( teacher/parent/children )
```

И код соответственно такой:

```
$res_login =
  mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = "'.$_POST['login'].'"' );
if (mysql_num_rows($res_login) != 1)
    echo 'Такой логин не зарегистрирован';
else {
    $row_login = mysql_fetch_array($res_login);
    if ($row_login['password'] != $_POST['password'])
        echo 'Вы ввели не правильный пароль';
    else {
        echo 'Пользователь авторизован';
        switch ( $row_login['type'] ){
          case 'teacher':
            echo 'Я учитель';
          break;
          case 'parent':
            echo 'Я родитель';
          break;
          case 'children':
            echo 'Я ребёнок';
          break;
          default:
            die('Ошибка в БД, неизвестный user.type');
        }

        if ( $row_login['type'] != 'parent' ) echo 'сюда можно только родителям';
        else {
          //Ваш код
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Y:\home\localhost\www\u\go.php on line 5
Такой логин не зарегистрированВы ввели не правильный парольОшибка в БД, неизвестный user.type

Comment: Так вы таблицу-то создали???

Comment: о черт, сорри я просто забыл  в 'SELECT * FROM `users`, поставить  свое имя.
СПС

Answer (score 1):

Полностью поддерживаю предыдущий ответ касаемо одной авторизационной таблицы, но если вы хотите проблем с тремя таблицами, то:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Логин: <input type="text" name="login" /><br />
    Пароль: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="teacher" /> Войти как учитель<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="student" /> Войти как ученнк<br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="parent" /> Войти как родитель<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Войти" />
</form>
```

Собственно то, что у вас уже есть:

```
<?php
if (
    !empty($_POST['type'] and
    preg_match('/^(teacher|student|parent)$/', $_POST['type'], $match)
) {
    $table = $match[0];
    $res_login = mysql_query(
        'SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `login` = "' . $_POST['login'] . '"'
    );
    if (mysql_num_rows($res_login) != 1)
        echo 'Такой логин не зарегистрирован';
    else {
        $row_login = mysql_fetch_array($res_login);
        if ($row_login['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
            echo 'Вы ввели не правильно пароль';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Пользователь авторизован';
        }
    }
}
```

Но это очень не гибкое решение. Я-бы не рекомендовал использовать подобную модель данных